# Opposing Teams: Who did Dillon pick?

Tags: pattern, word-property

Rudy Estabrook and Dillon O'Donnelly are chosen captains of opposing teams in a language trivia contest. They were asked to choose team members from a pool of their smart friends.

Here is how it went

> ```
>     Rudy's Choice         Dillon's choice
>     -------------         ---------------
>
>     Randal Lacey             Justin O'Neal
>
>     Rylon Gramwell           Josh Ortiz
>
>     Rico Mendez              Greg Olson
> ```
>
> Out of the remaining four ( Ozzie Daughtry, Andre Ventura, Rod
>   Dickerson and Robert Allanby)
>
> Rudy chose Rod. Who did Dillon choose? Why?

Hint

> Names of the captains have the same property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> Andre Ventura

Because

> Both names have opposites inside them, between their first and last names
>  Rud **y Es** tabrook - Dillo **n O** 'Donnelly - **YES / NO**
>  Rand **al L** acey - Justi **n O'Ne** al - **ALL / NONE**
>  Ry **lon G** ramwell - Jo **sh Ort** iz - **LONG / SHORT**
>  Ri **co Me** ndez - Gre **g O** lson - **COME / GO**
>  So, the final picks will be:
>  R **od D** ickerson - Andr **e Ven** tura - **ODD / EVEN**

Title

> Opposing Teams - Opposing Words

Comment: It's Ozzie Daughtry I feel sorry for... At least Robert Allanby had a chance of being picked against Josh Ortiz, but Ozzie was a no-hoper from the start...

Comment: Only if his name was spelled Daughtery then DickerSON Versus DAUGHTERy might had a chance. :)

Comment: @DEEM, great puzzle as always.

Answer (score 2):

He chose

> Robert Allanby

Because

> Rudy always chooses people whose *first* names start with the same (or similar) sound (not necessarily letter) as his own (i.e. /r/). Dillon uses the same strategy but with *last* names instead (assuming the A in "Allanby" is pronounced as in "all").

Note

> So, why Rudy did not choose Robert? Maybe, he made his choice after Dillon, we don't know the exact order.